# Get data from JQuery UI draggable and store in database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

This is what I want to do:

I want to take the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) associated with my draggable divs when they are dropped onto my droppable div and then store the data in a MySQL database, using PHP.

Please note that there will be multiple draggable divs that will be dropped on a single droppable div.

Also, the data will NOT be stored immediately; they will be stored at the click of a button when all the divs have been dragged.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery or another JS Tool / Framework to fire an AJAX request to your application. Build an interface which takes data e.g. the divId and the userId as well as the positionId. Note that you have to check the session by using the userId because the application security is affected if you allow this for each user.
You should return JSON (json_encode FTW!) to communicate with your javascript script.

**Database:**

```
id, userId, divId, positionId
1, 1, 1, 2
1, 1, 2, 1
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$positionId = $_GET['positionId'];
$divId      = $_GET['divId'];
$userId     = $_GET['userId']; // make sure that this userId is equal to your session

// init db
// check for existing entity (e.g. the div already exist for this user)
$db->query("INSERT INTO position SET userId = :userId, divId = :divId, positionId = :positionId");
// execute
json_encode(array('success' => true));
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your_script.php',
    params: {
        userId: 1,
        positionId: 1,
        divId: 1
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            // display feedback
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your reply...just wondering if this is the only way to do this, or, is there any other more efficient/professional way to do it?